# How to close second JFrame without terminating program

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, frame

How do I dispose my second frame while retaining my MainFrame?

I have a JFrame( CCurrencyConverterFrame) that I call from the Main Frame.

```
    JMenuItem mntmCurrencyConverter = new JMenuItem("Currency Converter");
    mntmCurrencyConverter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CCurrencyConverterFrame frame = new CCurrencyConverterFrame();
            myFrame = frame;
            JPanel contentPane = new CCurrencyConverter(myFrame);
            frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

In CCurrencyConverterFrame.java,

```
    public CCurrencyConverterFrame() {
    setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 12));
    getContentPane().setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    setTitle("Currency Converter ");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 469, 470);
    //Center
    setLocationRelativeTo(null) ;
    }
```

I have tried using JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE but it still terminates my application. What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: That's a very useful post. I decided to make use of JDialog and it works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. :)  Now you might write up an answer for this question, or delete it.